# Does zlib allow decompressing from the middle of a file

Tags: c, zlib

Does zlib allow decompressing from the middle of a file?
What I mean is, if I call `inflate` with a stream that points to the middle of compressed data without calling `inflate` to the data preceding the middle, would it work?

Comment: I was hoping that some people might already know the answer

Comment: I did read. I think I must've just missed it or forgotten about it :P

Comment: Almost every question on SO can be answered by RTFM. That doesn't make them bad questions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Copy from the [zlib FAQ](http://zlib.net/zlib_faq.html#faq28) (the emphasis is mine):

> 28. *Can I access data randomly in a compressed stream?*
>
> **No, not without some preparation.** If when compressing you periodically use `Z_FULL_FLUSH`, carefully write all the pending data at those points, and keep an index of those locations, then you can start decompression at those points. You have to be careful to not use `Z_FULL_FLUSH` too often, since it can significantly degrade compression. Alternatively, you can scan a deflate stream once to generate an index, and then use that index for random access. See examples/zran.c.